# Setting two variables equal in a multivariable holonomic function

Tags: combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations

If $f(x,y)$ is a holonomic (a.k.a. $D$-finite: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function) function of two complex (or real) variables, is $g(x)=f(x,x)$ also holonomic?